# Удаление файла используемого процессом

Tags: c#, .net

Есть программа .exe и библиотека .dll екзешник использует длл, мне нужно удалить длл. Сначала устанавливаю путь к ней `SelectedFile = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + "Theme_1_testing.dll");`,
потом пытаюсь удалить `File.Delete(SelectedFile);`. 
Длл не удаляется потому-что используется, можно ли как-то удалить её? Способ с динамическим подключением длл не предлагать.

Comment: Мне кажется вы хотите чего-то странного, зачем удалять `dll` если она используется? Может быть вы расскажете что вы пытаетесь решить удаляя `dll`

Comment: Я вообще делаю меню, в котором можно будет управлять этими dll, скачивать, удалять и выбирать, вот с удалением у меня и возникли проблемы.

Comment: Уточните кем именно используется dll. Вашей же программой (которая пытается ее удалить) - или другой?

Comment: Если файл будет использоваться процессом, то до того как ты закроешь процесс файл удалить не получится. Поэтому надо будет убивать процессы перед этим.

Comment: dll используется моей же программой, которая пытается её удалить. Может можно отключить её как-то?